# Execute process task fails to execute Rust script in job

Tags: sql-server, ssis, rust, ssms

I have written a small Rust script for an import job. I added the script execution into the SSIS package through the `Execute process task` and set the correct working directory. Using the debugger, the script works without a problem, as it does when executed normally, e.g. through `cmd` or PowerShell.

When I start the job in SSMS as an Agent Job, the package fails with

> The process exit code was "-1073741515" while the expected was "0".

#### What I tried

- Replacing the script with a very basic Rust script that just writes one single line to a file in the working directory to exclude the possibility that the script somehow panics, but still nothing.
- The script is compiled with the `i686-pc-windows-msvc` toolchain. With 64bit the script does not work at all on the server.
- Permissions look okay for the executing and the working directory. `Full control` for both folders.

Since execution works on the server I think this should most likely be a permissions issue but I can't for the life of me not figure out what is wrong.

Comment: when you say, "start the job in SSMS", do you mean start an Agent job or run the package from SSISDB?

Comment: That error code is `c0000135`, `STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND`. That's not generally a permissions issue, but a path or bitness issue. If all else fails and it's not clear from context, running [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) can give you the exact load that failed.

Comment: I just edited my question with some additional information: By "start the job in SSMS" I mean start an Agent job. I replaced the original script with a very basic Rust-script that just creates a file and writes "test" in it. Again, this script works fine as is on the server, but not in the job.

Comment: I'd guess its either related to the proxy account you configured to run SSIS jobs or that you should run it in 32-bit mode.  The latter can be required depending on what happens in the pkg

Comment: Hm, using 32bit runtime in the job step does nothing as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the problem was indeed with the default *SQL Server Service Agent*-account that ran the job. If I run the job with a Proxy-account it runs fine.

I'll have to look into the configuration of the Service Agent but until then, Proxy account it is.